# Why is my knex transaction throwing: Reference Error: <table> is not defined

Tags: node.js, postgresql, transactions, knex.js

I'm working through my first knex transaction using the transacting method.  The aim is for a set of three insert statements to atomically persist an incoming record's data into the three tables.  For context - the incoming record represents a parent object with two 1:M child relations - "a material has 0 to many properties and a material has 0 to many notes."  So I have a materials relation, a material_properties relation, and a material_notes relation.

I have a version of the method working which is not within a transaction.  But when I tried to wrap the functionality within a transaction, as specified in the [Knex documentation - 'Transaction' section](http://knexjs.org/#Transactions) - in the subsection "Same example as above using another await/async approach:", I am getting a reference error that the first child relation is not defined.  Additionally, I am getting an

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: trx is not defined

Note:  The parent table is inserted into first, and the reference error occurs when attempting to insert into the first child table: 'material_properties'.

Here's what worked:

```js
const materialRecord = {
            name: material.name,
            description: material.description ? material.description : null,
            user_id: userId
        }

/** 
 * Insert primary material into materials & get id value for FK
 */
const materialPrimaryKeyArray = await knex('materials')
  .returning('id')
  .insert(materialRecord)
  .catch(error => console.error(`Unable to persist record, ${error}`)) 
const materialPrimaryKey = materialPrimaryKeyArray[0];

/**
 * Persist properties and/or notes if they exist
 */
if (material.materialProperties) {
  material.materialProperties.forEach(property => {
    property['material_id'] = materialPrimaryKey
  });
  knex('material_properties')
    .returning('id')
    .insert(material.materialProperties)
    .catch(error => console.error(`Unable to persist record, ${error}`)) 
};

if (material.materialNotes) {
  material.materialNotes.forEach(note => {
    note['material_id'] = materialPrimaryKey
  });
  knex('material_notes')
    .returning('id')
    .insert(material.materialNotes)
    .catch(error => console.error(`Unable to persist record, ${error}`)) 
   };
   
return materialPrimaryKey;
```

Here is what isn't working:

```js
try {
  const materialRecord = {
    name: material.name,
    description: material.description ? material.description : null,
    user_id: userId
  }

  await knex.transaction(async trx => {
    const materialPrimaryKeyArray = await knex('materials')
      .insert(materialRecord, 'id')
      .transacting(trx)
    const materialPrimaryKey = materialPrimaryKeyArray[0];

    if (material.materialProperties && material.materialProperties.length > 0) {
      material.materialProperties.forEach(property => {
        property['material_id'] = materialPrimaryKey
      })

      const propertyInserts = await knex('material_properties')
        .insert(material.materialProperties, 'id')
        .transacting(trx)
      console.log(material_properties.length + ' properties attempted to save - ' + propertyInserts.length + ' properties successfully saved.')
    };

    if (material.materialNotes && material.materialNotes.length > 0) {
      material.materialNotes.forEach(note => {
        note['material_id'] = materialPrimaryKey
      })

      const noteInserts = await knex('material_notes')
        .insert(material.materialNotes, 'id')
        .transacting(trx)
      console.log(material_notes.length + ' properties attempted to save - ' + noteInserts.length + ' notes successfully saved.')
    };

    console.log('The material is successfully saved.')
  })

  return materialPrimaryKey;
} catch (error) {
  console.error(`Unable to persist data, ${error}`)
  trx.rollback
}
```

The table name is the same, as you can see in the assignment of "propertyInserts".

I tried promisifying each insert by adding the .catch between the insert and transacting methods:

```
            const materialPrimaryKeyArray = await knex('materials')
                .insert(materialRecord, 'id')
                .catch(error => `Cannot persist record, ${error}`)
                .transacting(trx)
            const materialPrimaryKey = materialPrimaryKeyArray[0];
```

.  When I did so, the ReferenceError for the table (material_properties) went away, and is replaced by a

> TypeError: (0 , _connection.default)(...).insert(...).catch(...).transacting is not a function

I also tried moving the catch statement below the transacting statement.  That didn't give the TypeError above, but it also didn't fix the UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning like I thought it might.

Note:  I actually got this to work with the first type of async/await transaction.  But I still can't tell why the transacting method isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access `trx` variable outside of its scope.

```
} catch (error) {
  console.error(`Unable to persist data, ${error}`)
  trx.rollback // here you are trying to use undefined variable
}
```

You can just remove that line. Since `knex.transaction(async trx => {})` threw an error, the transaction is automatically rolled back (because the handler function is retunrning a promise).

Also just accessing function without calling it wouldn't have made any difference `trx.rollback` and `trx.rollback()` doesn't do the same thing.